# Flutter - Get coordinates of the cursor within a TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, cursor, textfield, offset

I need to get the current cursor coordinates from a `TextField`.

There are some 'solutions' but none of them really works.

Tried using `controller.selection.baseOffset` multiplied with a hardcoded width per character which kinda works but only with a monospace font and only with one line.

Using a `FocusNode` combined with `TextPainter` like `focusNode.offset.dx + painter.width` is although not really precise.

So I don't think there is an easy way of getting the position of the cursor?

But maybe someone here had to face the same problem and could help me :)

Thanks Steven

Comment: there is `RenderEditable.onCaretChanged` property but in practice it would mean creating a custom widget that uses that `RenderEditable` render object - it does not pay off really,

Comment: if you want to check how it works setup a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f9c825981c/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/editable_text.dart#L2191) and watch `caretRect` while typing in your `TextField` (or using arrow keys - if you have them on your keyboard)

Comment: thanks man that is exactly what I was looking for, but now I am thinking about what would be the best approach to read this rect position from caret without changing the flutter source code?

Comment: so in line 1986 there is a `Rect` injected which seems to provide the necessary positioning of the caret.